# Create/Amend multiple objects (within a sproc) with different QUOTED_IDENTIFIER values

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, quoted-identifier

As a development aid, I am writing a stored procedure which creates/amends database objects from one database into another one.  (The sproc takes a CSV string of object names, which it splits into individual values using XML, and therefore the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` needs to be turned on for the sproc to run.)

However, the objects being created/amended include stored procedures where `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` could be turned either on or off.

According to the answer to this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324262/exec-and-set-quoted-identifier) (which talks specifically about creating a **single** stored procedure) if you create/amend a stored procedure within another stored procedure, it will *always* use the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` values set in the "parent" sproc.

**Does anybody know of a way to be able to set different `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` flag values when creating/amending multiple stored procedures?**

I've tried very simple code within the loop (such as the following) but as the above answer suggests, this has no effect on the result and the created/amended sproc always has `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` set to `ON`...

```
IF @QUOTED = 1 -- from sys.sql_modules.uses_quoted_identifier
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
ELSE
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

EXEC sp_executesql @DEFINITION -- from sys.sql_modules.definition
```

Comment: My idea would be to write another sproc to do `sp_executesql` for you, this one with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` explicitly set to `OFF`, and call it when you need to.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen - the issue there is that I'm processing the CSV of object names using XML, and therefore I need it set to `ON`.  It would also mean more time in having to work out which sprocs were `ON` and which were `OFF` to allocate to the appropriate development-aid sproc.  In an "ideal world" I have a single dev-aid sproc that I throw all the object names at, and it copes (so I don't have to!)

Comment: @Jeroen - of course, what I **could** have is three sprocs... the primary one, which then calls one of two secondary ones depending on if it needs `ON` or `OFF`.  I'll get back to you

Comment: Yes, I understand  the "master" sproc needs it `ON`, but you will not get around having to query what the setting for a stored procedure is now (your `@QUOTED` above) so if you do, you can do `IF @QUOTED = 0 EXEC MyCreatingProcedureThatHasQIOff @Definition`, with `MyCreatingProcedureThatHasQIOff` just a really stupid proxy for an `EXEC` command.

Comment: @Jeroen - bingo - that was it... thank you for sending me down that path.  If you'd like the credit, please write an answer, otherwise I'll write one myself explaining the creation of 3 sprocs (1 primary, 2 sub)

Comment: You technically need only the one sub, since the master will always be `ON` itself. Though you might do that for symmetry purposes, I suppose.

Comment: @Jeroen - an excellent point! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many thanks to [@Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) who sent me down the path to the solution, which is to create another development-aid stored procedure with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` set to `OFF`.

Within the main loop of the primary development-aid sproc it executes the definition through itself (if `ON` is required) or through the secondary sproc (if `OFF` is required).

This is a **very simplified pseudo** version of what I now have working...

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DEV_AID_SUB
  @DEFINITION NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
  EXEC sp_executesql @DEFINITION

---

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DEV_AID
AS
BEGIN
  WHILE @LOOP = 1
    IF @QUOTED = 1
      EXEC sp_executesql @DEFINITION
    ELSE
      EXEC DEV_AID_SUB @DEFINITION
  END
END
```